# Data doesn't get transferred correctly to USB, why?

Tags: usb

I have Ubuntu 13.10, and whenever I copy something to USB sometimes it works but mostly when I check the data on other machine (with Windows or Ubuntu) it shows nothing or if it does then its partial data for example if it was a movie or a video then it would be of few minutes not full video, same case is with any other files. I have tried to format the USB several times and send the data again, but it doesn't do anything, and sometimes it transfer the data perfect. So I don't know what exactly I should do?

Note: I have tried many USB's

Comment: After transferring the data to the USB do you Unmount it properly?

Comment: @Tarun yes i do unmount it properly, the data transfer is so high like 55 mbs and it just complete in few seconds and then nothing and i check on other system it shows partial or nothing

Comment: Have you tried using `cp`?

Comment: yes i have tried `cp` and its doing the same

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like (given your description of fast transfers) that it's copying through a buffer but that hasn't been flushed to disk before you unplug it. This is fairly common.

You can force all your system disks to sync with their buffers by running `sync`. This is a blocking command so you won't be able to type while it's working.

"Safely Eject Device" (or however that's worded) should be running a `sync` (that's what it *means*) but if you are using that, it sounds like that isn't working and you should report a bug.

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and type as

```
rsync -avviu /source/path /destination/path/of usb
```

at the end of transmission it will display the errors if any.

Comment: When i type this `rsync -avviu Desktop/DSCN4927.MOV /media/waqas/D230BFA930BF92C9/` and this shows this `sending incremental file list
delta-transmission disabled for local transfer or --whole-file
DSCN4927.MOV is newer
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=0

sent 54 bytes  received 12 bytes  132.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1089685086  speedup is 16510380.09
` and file have the same issue.

Comment: seems to be a bug , you might report it to launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command to copy the files via **terminal**

```
cp -Ri /path/to/source/folder1 /path/to/destination/folder2/
```

`folder1` - folder consists of files which you are going to copy
`folder2` - destination folder in which you are going to paste folder1

Comment: I tried this on few file transfers and it worked fine first time but again its not working now ! and giving this error `This location could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents of “58FA26B9FA2692F4”: Error when getting information for file '/media/rana/58FA26B9FA2692F4/netbeans-7.4-linux.sh': Input/output error`

Comment: what would to a usb be?