# Copying issue in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: usb-drive

While copying files from the pen-drive, the copying speed gradually slows down. Copying rate is too slow and stops at the last moment. The dialogue box shows remaining time is 0 seconds, but copying is not finished yet. This happen only when copying from the pen-drive, this doesn't happen when copying from the pen drive.

Comment: if you remove the pen drive after it shows 0 seconds what happens ? you data is not copied properly or its fine ?

Comment: My datas are not copied properly @RanaMuhammadWaqas

Comment: try [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372990/data-doesnt-get-transferred-correctly-to-usb-why)  might help you and let me know the results